# Best Way to load Static Data in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark project that makes use of some static metadata about states/regions.  Currently the data is hardcoded like so:

```
object RegionUtil {
   val regionNames = Map("US-AL" -> "ALABAMA",
                  "US-AK" -> "ALASKA",
                  "US-AZ" -> "ARIZONA",
                  "US-AR" -> "ARKANSAS",
                  "US-CA" -> "CALIFORNIA",
                  "US-CO" -> "COLORADO",
                  // ... etc
                  "US-WY" -> "WYOMING")
 }
```

And then region mappings are simply looked up from the map in RegionUtil.  This is just an example as there are a number of similar static mappings the application relies on.

But some of this metadata is occasionally (rarely) updated, and is already maintained in a MySQL database.  What I would like to do is initially load that data when spark starts up, and then look up a cached copy of that data from that point forward (ideally with each slave node maintaining its own copy) whenever metadata needs to be accessed.

Does anyone know how that can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into [broadcasting](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) for this purpose:

*Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks. They can be used, for example, to give every node a copy of a large input dataset in an efficient manner. Spark also attempts to distribute broadcast variables using efficient broadcast algorithms to reduce communication cost.*

And their code example:

```
val broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(Array(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

If you create /update the structure without using spark (e.g. using Slick or JDBC directly or whatever) before you write the spark specific code and the value holding the data will be in scope and used in the spark code, spark will serialize and broadcast it for you.

If you need these to be updated during the spark job run then you need to use broadcast